# Android OnInfoWindowClickListener() never called

Tags: android, google-maps, callback, google-maps-markers, eventtrigger

I'm creating an application with new Google Maps API V2 and I have to intercept the click on InfoWindow, showed when a Marker is clicked.

Reading the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#info_window_click_events) I assumed that I do that to listen to InfoWindows clicks :

```
 mGoogleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

            Log.d("", marker.getTitle());   
        }
    });
```

But unfortunatly the method is never called.

If I try to listen to marker click and use setOnMarkerClickListener instead of OnInfoWindowClickListener , this works fine.

Hope to find some help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The OnInfoWindowClickListener gets called when you actually click on the Marker title popup and not the marker.

The above just works fine.

Comment: yes, it works fine now. I where adding the OnInfoWindowClickListener two times insead only one time. Just my mistake!